# What does a single apostrophe mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, actor

In this slide show on [ScalaActors.pdf](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~phaller/doc/ScalaActors.pdf) what does the single quote indicate when the message is sent to the pong actor?

```
class Ping(count: int, pong: Pong) extends Actor {
def act() {
   pong ! 'Ping // what does the single quote indicate???
      receive {
         case 'Pong =>
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How is this question closed as the duplicate when it predates the other question by several years?

Answer (score 15):

It indicates a Symbol.  Eg. cfr http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Symbol.html :

> the Scala  term 'mysym will invoke the constructor of the Symbol class in the following way: Symbol("mysym").