# What does 'col (with tick) expression mean in Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The following syntax:

```
def func0(x: Int => Int, y: Int)(in: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    in.filter('col > x(y))
}
```

Cannot place the 'col. "col" does not work, whereas "col" does work in the following code fine:

```
def func1(x: Int)(in: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    in.selectExpr("col", s"col + $x as col1")
}
```

The `'col` signifies?

The dataframe example only has one col, `col`, what if 2 or 3 cols? Clearly missing something here. Something tells me it is very simple.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/918590/2093695

Comment: Not the same thing I think though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'col` is a way to refer to a column named `col`, same as `$"col"` or `col("col")` It's a bit confusing to have a column named `col`.

It's working for me in spark 2.3

**EXAMPLE WITH A COLUMN NAMED NUMBER**

```
df.show
+------+------+
|letter|number|
+------+------+
|     a|     1|
|     b|     2|
+------+------+

df.filter('number >1).show
+------+------+
|letter|number|
+------+------+
|     b|     2|
+------+------+
```

Same with the other expressions

```
import spark.implicits._
df.filter($"number" >1).show

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
df.filter(col("number") >1).show
```

Comment: Is there a difference between using `$` and `col` performance wise?

Comment: I don't think so, just different APIs