# How to convert a DataFrame map column to a struct column?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, dictionary, struct, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have a `DataFrame` with a column of `map` type.

```scala
val df = spark.sql("""select map("foo", 1, "bar", 2) AS mapColumn""")
df.show()
// +--------------------+
// |           mapColumn|
// +--------------------+
// |{foo -> 1, bar -> 2}|
// +--------------------+
```

What is the most straightforward way to convert it to a `struct` (or, equivalently, define a new column with the same keys and values but as a `struct` type)?  See the following `spark-shell` (2.4.5) session, for an insanely inefficient way of going about it:

```scala
val jsonStr = df.select(to_json($"mapColumn")).collect()(0)(0).asInstanceOf[String]

spark.read.json(Seq(jsonStr).toDS()).show()
// +---+---+
// |bar|foo|
// +---+---+
// |  2|  1|
// +---+---+
```

Now, obviously `collect()` is very inefficient, and this is generally an awful way to do things in Spark.  But what is the preferred way to accomplish this conversion?  [`named_struct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/sql/index.html#named_struct) and [`struct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/sql/index.html#struct) both take a sequence of parameter values to construct the results, but I can't find any way to "unwrap" the map key/values to pass them to these functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `explode` function:

```
+--------------------+
|           mapColumn|
+--------------------+
|[foo -> 1, bar -> 2]|
+--------------------+
```

`df.select(explode('mapColumn)).select(struct('*).as("struct"))`

output:

```
+--------+
|  struct|
+--------+
|[foo, 1]|
|[bar, 2]|
+--------+

root
 |-- struct: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- value: integer (nullable = false)
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want, but the weird, seemingly unbalanced single quotes are throwing me off...

Comment: in case it's not obvious, in a real life scenario with multiple columns you would use `.select('*', struct('mapCol'))`

Comment: I finally learned that my confusion was due to the Symbol syntax.  I.e. this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/918613/375670

Answer (score 1):

I see @chlebek answer but in case it should be kept in one row you can use an UDF

```scala
scala> val df = spark.sql("""select map("foo", 1, "bar", 2) AS mapColumn""")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [mapColumn: map<string,int>]

scala> df.show
+--------------------+
|           mapColumn|
+--------------------+
|[foo -> 1, bar -> 2]|
+--------------------+

scala> case class KeyValue(key: String, value: String)
defined class KeyValue

scala> val toArrayOfStructs = udf((value: Map[String, String]) => value.map {
     |   case (k, v) => KeyValue(k, v)
     | }.toArray )
toArrayOfStructs: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(key,StringType,true), StructField(value,StringType,true)),true),Some(List(MapType(StringType,StringType,true))))

scala> df.withColumn("alfa", toArrayOfStructs(col("mapColumn")))
res4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [mapColumn: map<string,int>, alfa: array<struct<key:string,value:string>>]

scala> res4.show
+--------------------+--------------------+
|           mapColumn|                alfa|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[foo -> 1, bar -> 2]|[[foo, 1], [bar, 2]]|
+--------------------+--------------------+


scala> res4.printSchema
root
 |-- mapColumn: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
 |-- alfa: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method doesn't seem to work with more rows, and especially if they have different maps, like this one:

```scala
val df = Seq(
    (Map("foo"->1, "bar"->2)),
    (Map("foo"->3, "baz"->4))
).toDF("mapColumn")

df.show()
// +--------------------+
// |           mapColumn|
// +--------------------+
// |{foo -> 1, bar -> 2}|
// |{foo -> 3, baz -> 4}|
// +--------------------+
```

Your script would return...

```scala
val jsonStr = df.select(to_json($"mapColumn")).collect()(0)(0).asInstanceOf[String]
spark.read.json(Seq(jsonStr).toDS()).show()
// +---+---+
// |bar|foo|
// +---+---+
// |  2|  1|
// +---+---+
```

**Solutions**

- map to columns:

  ```scala
  val json_col = to_json($"mapColumn")
  val json_schema = spark.read.json(df.select(json_col).as[String]).schema
  val df2 = df.withColumn("_c", from_json(json_col, json_schema)).select("_c.*")

  df2.show()
  // +----+----+---+
  // | bar| baz|foo|
  // +----+----+---+
  // |   2|null|  1|
  // |null|   4|  3|
  // +----+----+---+
  ```
- map to struct (field names: "key", "value"):

  ```scala
  val df2 = df.select(explode(map_entries($"mapColumn")).as("struct"))
  df2.show()
  // +--------+
  // |  struct|
  // +--------+
  // |{foo, 1}|
  // |{bar, 2}|
  // |{foo, 3}|
  // |{baz, 4}|
  // +--------+
  ```
- map to struct (field names: "foo", "bar", "baz"):

  ```scala
  val json_col = to_json($"mapColumn")
  val json_schema = spark.read.json(df.select(json_col).as[String]).schema
  val df2 = df.select(from_json(json_col, json_schema).as("struct"))

  df2.show()
  // +------------+
  // |      struct|
  // +------------+
  // |{2, null, 1}|
  // |{null, 4, 3}|
  // +------------+
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Define a case class

```
case class Bean56(foo: Int, bar: Int)
```

```
//Define a bean Encoder
val personEncoder = Encoders.bean[Bean56](classOf[Bean56])

    val df = spark.sql("""select map("foo", 1, "bar", 2) AS mapColumn""")

//Map the output to required bean
    val Bean56s = df.map(row => {
      val map = row.getMap[String, Int](0)
      Bean56(map.getOrElse("foo", -1), map.getOrElse("bar", -1))
    })(personEncoder)  // Supply implicit Encoder of the bean
    Bean56s.foreach(println(_)) // Print the bean
```